# How to analyze the behaviour of the extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

We are working on the behaviour/monitor of google chrome extensions. We want to find out which extension is requesting which link/url/scripts.

We want to analyze the activity of extension.

The question is there any method or script where we can collect the requesting data from extension?

Comment: show us your research and attempts so far. else too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires a whitelisted api: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activityLogPrivate

You will need to load unpacked and add this to the manifest:

"key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDV/GMX7sjLe3ceUizalvfZK0qhsWnXcjJ3cCbYvXFo43Q2F7SZM8/0roex0wSpNRSO1j9c/m7YXLYBAOiy21ERRJEVEIvOvWp1LLeoBSsbQnnhSPKInqUrkA8fMRCqI0gHRUK3K7dIiOC2A7jkWUMs4DqRiQSkntUUGzVIoY6OYQIDAQAB"